# Not applying subdivide modifier increases render time

Tags: rendering, animation, modifiers, subdivision-surface

I'm using blender 2.8 and I've noticed that my render time on animations is drastically increased if I don't apply the Subdivision Surface modifiers before rendering. It's as if it's having to apply the modifier on every frame. Does anyone else get this? Do I just need to keep remembering to apply the modifier before rendering and then undo it afterwards?